# How to export data from rethinkdb for few columns

Tags: rethinkdb

using below command, how will we export data from rethinkDB where author='ABC'

rethinkdb export -e dbname.posts --format csv --fields title,author

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your data in a new temp table and export that table:

```
r.db("dbname").table("post")
    .filter({"author":"ABC"})
    .map(function(doc){
        return r.db("dbname").table("temp").insert(doc)
})
```

then you export the temp table

```
rethinkdb dump -e dbname.temp ...
```